# JavaScript ascii to utf-8 conversion problems with negatives

Tags: javascript, encryption, utf-8, ascii

I'm working on decrypting server side information I have the encryption working in a different language and therefore know what the decryption should be?

Why don't negative numbers come out correct when positives do?

Run Example:

Output Format:

```
str
pos
S[t]
str.charAt(str, pos + 1)
str.charCodeAt(pos + 1)
```

decryption according to GML:

```
Input:
Str: ���
Key: 472
--------------
str: ���
pos: 0
ST: 195
char: ⮫
value: -94

str: ���
pos: 1
ST: 140
char: 
value: -18

str: ���
pos: 2
ST: 136
char: 
value: -21
```

Server Side Equivalent (JS):

```
Input: 
Str: ���
Key: 472
---------------
str: ���
pos: 0
ST: 195
char: �
value: 65533

str: ���
pos: 1
ST: 140
char: �
value: 65533

str: ���
pos: 2
ST: 136
char: 
value: NaN
```

How information gets to the input:
data is passed from Server.js -> Client.js where the header is taken and put through a switch statment, the rest of the datapacket is then parsed using:

```
var Parser = require('binary-parser').Parser;

login: new Parser().skip(1)
        .string("command", StringOptions)
        .string("username", StringOptions)
        .string("password", StringOptions),
```

then is inputed to the method:
console.log(rc4(data.password, c.dhprivatekey));

My code if needed:

```
function rc4(str, key) {
    var out = "";
    var len = byteCount(key);
    var S = [], j;
    var t;
    for(var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        S[i] = i;
    }
    j = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i< 256; i++) {

        var test = string_byte_at(key, (i % len) + 1)[0];

        if (typeof test != "number") {
        test = parseInt(test);

        }
        j = (j + S[i] + test % 256);
        temp = S[i];
        S[i] = S[j];
        S[j] = temp;
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 0;


    for (var pos = 0; pos < str.length; pos++) {
        i = (i + 1) % 256;
        j = (j + S[i]) % 256;
        var temp = S[i];
        S[i] = S[j];
        S[j] = temp;
        t = (S[i] + S[j]) % 256;
        out += str.charCodeAt(string_byte_at(str, pos + 1)[0] ^ S[t]);

    }
    return out;
    }
```

Correctly working decryption in GML

```
 var str,key,out,len,i,S,j,temp,pos,t;
str = argument0;
key = string(argument1);
out = "";
len = string_byte_length(key);
for (i=0; i<256; i+=1) S[i] = i;
j = 0;
for (i=0; i<256; i+=1) {
    //show_debug_message(string_byte_at(key, (i mod len) + 1));
    j = (j + S[i] + string_byte_at(key,(i mod len)+1)) mod 256;
    temp = S[i];
    S[i] = S[j];
    S[j] = temp;
}
i = 0;
j = 0;

for (pos=0; pos < string_byte_length(str); pos+=1) {
    i = (i + 1) mod 256;
    j = (j + S[i]) mod 256;
    temp = S[i];
    S[i] = S[j];
    S[j] = temp;
    t = (S[i] + S[j]) mod 256;

    out += ansi_char(string_byte_at(str,pos+1) ^ S[t]);

}
return out;
```

http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/strings/string_byte_at.html

http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/strings/ansi_char.html

http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=554460

Comment: Are you trying to decrypt the binary values, or the string? You are getting positive values because a `char code`s are strictly non-negative. What makes you expect negative?

Comment: The equivalent I am using outputs using a function which "returns a string containing the character with raw BYTE value set." it takes a "raw byte input which is gained by taking the value of a byte in the string". and the raw byte input is sometimes negative. idk if that's useful or not.

Comment: Can you post the encryption function that is working? Also, what language is it? Different languages have different behaviors for strings. Bytes are just bits, they have no sign, so there has to be something else here. Also, how are you transferring the information to JS? Is this running in Node, or in a browser?

Comment: Added the working code, might take a bit of googling to work out the functions if you haven't used game maker before. Data is transfered though tcp sockets and yes this is running in node js.

Comment: Cool! If it is in node, I would't use a string at all. That said, can you give an example input, key and the expected output too? But show an example input as `new Buffer(str)`. Also, can I ask how you are getting `str` to pass to this function?  Your `GML` code outputs a byte string, which will probably get corrupted because node uses UTF16 strings. It would be better to read the data directly into a node `Buffer` instance.

Comment: Sorry it was 2am I had to sleep, i've added the example you asked for, if I make str = new Buffer(str); it just gives an error saying "Object %�� has no method 'charCodeAt'" cause its a buffer now not a string. The information is parsed through binary-parser before the correct section is gained then put through.

Comment: Update: Since I have found a LOAD of problems with data transfer, things were being send in U32 and read in S16 etc.. which meant keys were different, ive redone it and key are correct etc, yet it still get my original problem, i've posted updated examples.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. This question had enough pieces that it is really hard to answer on its own.

Comment: Yeah it did, You pointed me in the direction of what to look at and check, that helped a lot thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason my code wasn't working was down to a number of reasons:
The connection between client and server was outputing unsigned 32 bit integers while trying to input signed 16 bit integers which make the keys unequal.

Once that was fixed the reason why I was getting negative numbers is purely because of the difference between the Game Maker Language and JavaScript.

In JavaScript you can convert string to and from ascii however in gml from what I can gather they have combined ascii with others to give a range from -256 to 256 of symbols like Chinese, Japanese and Latin which aren't included in ascii or ascii extended.

To resolve my problem I had to prevent gml from encoding like this and stick to just the normal ascii characters this allows me to read and decrypt properly in JavaScript.